# Program crashes on close Event in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I was trying to set the close event to my code but when I set this code my program crashes.

mainwindow.cpp

```
 void MainWindow::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event)
    {
        event->ignore();

        if (QMessageBox::Yes == QMessageBox::question(this, "Close Confirmation?",
                                                      "Are you sure you want to exit?",
                                                      QMessageBox::Yes|QMessageBox::No))
        {
            if(QMessageBox::Yes)
            {
                if(aboutDialog)
                {
                    aboutDialog->close();
                    event->accept();
                }
                event->accept();
            }
        }
    }

void MainWindow::showAboutDialog()
{
    aboutDialog = new QDialog;
    Ui::About aboutUi;
    aboutUi.setupUi(aboutDialog);
    connect(aboutUi.Close, SIGNAL(pressed()), aboutDialog, SLOT(close()));
    aboutDialog->show();
}
```

mainwindow.h

```
private:
QDialog *aboutDialog;
```

I am confused why this happens. Help me out to solve this!

Comment: Besides of the fact that your code is also confusing, whet happens if you remove this `aboutDialog->close();` call? Does it also crash?

Comment: aboutDialog is the dialog box which is in the program. If i remove this program doesnot crashes but on closing whole progam that dialog box remain open. But with closing of program Dialog box should also get closed if it is open

Comment: @user4345796 You can pass the pointer to main window as the parent of `aboutDialog` when instantiating to make it close when main window is closed : `QDialog * aboutDialog = new QDialog(this);`

Comment: I didn't get you. How should I do this, means what should I do to proceed for the above?

Comment: You should have in the constructor of `MainWindow` :  `aboutDialog = new QDialog(this);`

Comment: @Nejat Thanks, this helped me out to solve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't ignore the event if you're planning to close, try this:

```
void MainWindow::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event)
{
    if (QMessageBox::Yes != QMessageBox::question(this, "Close Confirmation?",
        "Are you sure you want to exit?", QMessageBox::Yes | QMessageBox::No))
    {
        event->ignore();
    }
}
```

And when creating the `aboutDialog`-box, you should pass the `mainWindow` as parent as Nejat's comment suggests: `aboutDialog = new QDialog(mainWindow);`. This will make sure that the `aboutDialog` will get closed if the main window closes.

Comment: Calling `close()` function from the close event? Won't this cause the recursive calls for `closeEvent()`?

Comment: It works but the problem is that about Dialog remains open even on closing the program so proble presists there only.